# ForEach Loop failing to continue on the file?

Tags: powershell

The ForEach loop on this powershell script is failing to run more than one item before dropping out?

Can someone help me on this one?

```
function Get-RemoteLogonStatus {
    [CmdletBinding()]
   
    param(
        [string]$ComputerName = ' '
    )
 
    ForEach ($line in Get-Content C:\ADComputers.csv) 
    { 
        $Computername = $line

        if ( Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 3 -Quiet ) {
            try {
                Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $ComputerName –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName = $lname -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
            }
            catch {
                Write-Output 'No user logged in - RESTARTING.'
                Shutdown /r /t 0  /M \\$ComputerName
                $ComputerName    
                return
            } 

            Write-Output 'Computer in use.'
            $ComputerName
        }
        else {
            Write-Output 'Computer in Use or is Offline.'
            $ComputerName
        }
    } 
    $error.clear
}

Get-RemoteLogonStatus
```

Should run more than one item from the file.  The file has 4 items for test:

Comment: [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return) will exit your script. Remove the `Try`/`Catch` blocks to debug and reveal what's really going on.

Comment: `Select-Object UserName = $lname -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null`, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: THANK YOU GENTLEMEN!    Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. a function is supposed to contain a block of code that can be repeated a number of times. Your function does all in one go, hence I don't see the need for it. Also it has the possibility to take one argument, but you don't pass it.
2. 'return' is not necessary in PowerShell, it will throw the content of a variable without the need for  a 'return'.
3. Select-Object needs a name that is being passed from the pipe, and not an assignment.
4. inside the try statement you might want to get an output, but if you pipe the line to Out-null you get nothing. and the catch will never grab any error.
5. the write-output are not clearly positioned, and difficult to understand.

I can infer what you are trying to achieve is: reboot computers in the csv file IF no user is logged in, is that so? In that case it's much simpler:

```
foreach ($ComputerName in (Get-Content C:\ADComputers.csv)) {
  $User = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object UserName

  if ($User.UserName -eq $null) {
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $ComputerName -Force
  }
}
```

of if you want to stick to a function and see its purpose see this:

```
function Restart-Node {
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ComputerName
  )
  
  $User = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object UserName
  if ($User.UserName -eq $null) {
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $ComputerName -Force
  }
}

foreach ($ComputerName in (Get-Content C:\ADComputers.csv)) {
  Restart-Node -ComputerName $ComputerName
}
```